# Total number of rows where columns contain data

Tags: arrays, excel, math

I'm trying to tally the number of shelters that have a need, any need.

So the problem is, count the number of rows where specified columns contain any data.

### example

```
|Shelter|Food|Water|Blankets|
|-------|----|-----|--------|
|S(A)   |  X |     |        |       
|S(B)   |  y |  x  |        |
|S(C)   |    |     |        |
```

```
Total Shelters with a need: 2
```

=COUNTIF(FOR( S(A):S( C),OR(Food:Blankets))

I tried

=COUNTIF(ROW24:ROW27,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Food:Blankets,"*"))>0)

But that doesn’t work. It produces a 0. It seems like there might be a matrix math solution but I can't find it. Also it seems like there should be an Excel Array math solution that is elegant but after many attempts I can't get anything to work. I know I can create a cumbersome formula that simply includes every cell range row by row but I'm hoping for more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [COUNTA](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ways-to-count-cells-in-a-range-of-data-3e0b3b7a-e0e4-478a-a940-889400120072) function in combination with an IF statement.

From Microsoft:

> COUNTA: To count cells that are not empty

Create a fifth column to track if a given shelter is in need. Return 1 if there is a need and 0 if there is not. The formula would be something like:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B3:D3)>0, 1, 0)
```

Use SUM() in the footer of that column to calculate the total shelters in need.

[image: Expected output]

Comment: Isn't that going to return a 3, not a 2?

Comment: @user10981853 - Thanks for encouraging greater clarity. I edited my response a to include a precise formula. It returns the expected total.

Answer (score 0):

Us a SUMPRODUCT based on the length of the concatenated values.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(LEN(B24:B27&C24:C27&D24:D27)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for =SUMPRODUCT(SIGN(LEN(B24:B27&C24:C27&D24:D27))), it works! A wonderful solution, no other interim calculation cells needed, compact, elegant.